# how to import a table with a self relationship

Tags: ssis, referential-integrity, self-reference, self-referencing-table

I have the following table:

EntityId - PK
Label
ParentEntityId - FK

ParentEntityId is joined to EntityId of the same table. now I am having problems importing data to this table using SSIS because of instances where the parent entities haven't been imported yet and so I get a FK constraint violation. I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the foreign key prior to loading the data, then re-enable it after loading completes, both using T-SQL.

Eg - to disable - `ALTER TABLE yourTableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT yourConstraintName`

To re-enable - `ALTER TABLE yourTableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT yourConstraintName`